# Display images in a folder, slider style (one by one) by swiping or clicking, with multiple select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a website coded with standard stuff (html, javascript, jquery, php). I have a folder that I will dump images into throughout the day. I need to be able to access the website on a tablet, swipe from image to image and be able to select one or more (by filename) and then pass that list to the next procedure.

I do primarily database forms and such, not sure about the displaying of images and the swiping and keeping track of the selected images. Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated! I don't really expect anyone to do my work...just not sure where to start (yes, I've been Googling for a while).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many different possibilities in solving your issue. You can use [Bootstrap's Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/). It works fairly well; and assuming you're using PHP, you can create elements based on the directory content.

Your base code for the Carousel - straight from Bootstrap's content:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

To make a automated PHP script you could use `scandir` and use a `foreach` loop to loop through the content:

```
<?php
$dir = './images/';
$file_list = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));

foreach($file_list as $item)
{
    echo '<div class="carousel-item">';
    echo '<img="' . $item . '" class="d-block w-100">';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

That will create a loop based on the files in that directory.

Comment: Thanks! Now, Is that allowing me to swipe to switch images? Also, how would you handle the selectable part?

Comment: Yes, the carousel will allow you to see the pictures and swipe back and forth from them. Also, you can add an anchor (`<a>`) between your image tag to link it back to your image.

Comment: @MichaelMac you can read their [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) online and it has a bunch of options you can use. It's a pretty solid library.

Comment: Ok. This is great for displaying and swiping, but I still don't see how I would do the selectable part (multiple select images).

Comment: Oh, my bad, I thought you were asking how to go to the image itself, you can create thumbnails underneath the carousel, just add individual `img` tags there